# Turbolinks is Stopping xhr request on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

On my website I am making a jquery request every 5ms to get some data from my server. The request works fine until I press a link on my website and redirect back. After that my website stops polling the server with the last initiator being turbolinks. I have followed all the turbolinks instructions and added all the required gems and additions to my application.js file yet I get the same problem. When I delete the turbolinks gem, my website loses it ability to redirect from button clicks on the site. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: what version or rails and turbolinks are you using? did you install the gem jquery-turbolinks if you are not using turbolinks 5 and rails 5

Comment: I am using rails 5.1.3, its weird though once I redirect back once from the site all buttons stop working, meaning the javascript code does not run, I did install jquery-turbolinks though

Comment: Jquery-turbolinks does not work with rails turbolinks 5

Comment: Y can disable turbolinks for those links

Comment: Please show some relevant code and the Gemfile.